# Empty figures with basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to use model output on flows in a tidal basin. The model uses a curvilinear grid. My first task is to just plot one component of the velocity of the highest water layer. I wrote a little bit of code based on the question under the name: Matplotlib Streamplot for Unevenly (curvilinear) Grid.

Now as far as I can see, I didn't change anything essential except for the numbers in comparison to the earlier metioned question, but the figures remain empty. I put the code and some numbers below.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Lat = np.array([[ 30.40098833,  30.40103752,  30.40108727,  30.40113704],
 [ 30.40140046,  30.40145021,  30.40149997,  30.40154973],
 [ 30.40186559,  30.40191478,  30.40196453,  30.4020143 ],
 [ 30.40239781,  30.402447,    30.40249676,  30.40254652]])

Lon = np.array([[-86.51729818, -86.51794126, -86.5185871,  -86.51923603],
 [-86.51725858, -86.51790149, -86.51854717, -86.51919595],
 [-86.51721383, -86.51785659, -86.51850228, -86.51915089],
 [-86.51716242, -86.51780518, -86.51845087, -86.51909948]])

Xvel = np.array([[ 0.0325774,  -0.02811189, -0.04972513, -0.07736091],
 [ 0.00592685, -0.00043959, -0.00735147, -0.05015078],
 [-0.03365543, -0.03183309, -0.03701356, -0.07232581],
 [-0.09578606, -0.10139448, -0.11220678, -0.13221299]])


plt.ion()
fig,(ax1) = plt.subplots(1,1)

m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=Lon.min(),llcrnrlat=Lat.min(),
urcrnrlon=Lon.max(), urcrnrlat=Lat.max(),
projection='merc',resolution='i',ax=ax1)

m.contourf(Lat,Lon,Xvel,latlon=True)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawrivers()
m.plot(Lat,Lon,'-k',alpha=0.3,latlon=True)
m.plot(Lat.T,Lon.T,'-k',alpha=0.3,latlon=True)
```

Could someone tell me what it is that causes the plots to remain empty?

I have another question regarding the use of Basemap: My datasheet also contains a lot of NaN's (gridpoints with no information). I was wondering how I can let Basemap know that I just don't have any information on these positions and that I don't want any plotting there. In the current code it causes an 'Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring' error.

Comment: I'm not sure what it's supposed to look like, but I have a couple of notes - 1) In your plot you should be doing `(Lon, Lat)` rather than `(Lat, Lon)`, and 2) the area encompassed by the lat/lons in this example is quite small, which is probably why the coastlines and rivers don't show up.

Comment: I keep getting `ImportError: No module named basemap` butg it might be that you have to end with `plt.show()`

Comment: @ Ajean: Thanks a lot, it was indeed just the Lat/Lon switch. And you're right about the small area, but I was mainly interested in the 'Xvel'. If I increase the area I do get the coastlines.

@DrBwts: Thanks for your answer, I think the import error is because you might not have installed the Basemap package, and the plotting works through plt.ion(), it is some kind of interactive mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the second part of your question (since Ajean appears to have solved the first half), the standard way to tell Matplotlib (and hence Basemap) to not plot data is to create a masked array. Lets say your Xvel contained NaNs, then to plot it you would do

```
import numpy.ma as ma
m.contourf(Lon, Lat, ma.masked_invalid(Xvel), latlon=True)
```

the function ma.masked_invalid, as its name implies, masks all invalid (i.e., NaN) values, so that they're not plotted.